# Append text field data to an existing JSON file in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a text field where user can enter data, once data is received i want to append it to existing JSON file.

I am able to read the existing data and getting the text field value, but while appending the new data with existing data I'm facing problem.

Error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 18 path $
```

Below code :

JSON File :

```
{"vins":[{"vin":"544554"},{"vin":"54554"}]}
```

Text field value : String test ="3689";
so it should be appended as :

```
{"vins":[{"vin":"544554"},{"vin":"54554"},{"vin":"3689"}]}
```

Filereadwrite class :

```
public class JSONFIlewrite {
    public static String Vinno_Read;
    public static List<String> linststring;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new 
            FileReader("C:\\Amaresh\\Test\\sample_json.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            linststring= new ArrayList();
            // loop array
            JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("vins");
            Iterator iterator = msg.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Vinno_Read = iterator.next().toString();

                linststring.add(Vinno_Read);


            }

            String list_string = "";
            System.out.println(linststring);

            for(String temp:linststring){
                list_string += temp;
                System.out.println("amar1"+list_string);
            }

            System.out.println("amar"+list_string);
            Vin vin4 = new Vin();
            vin4.setVin("76354273462");
            Vins vins = new Vins();
            vins.addVins(vin4);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            //String jsonValue=list_string;

            String jsonValue = gson.toJson(list_string).toString();
            System.out.println("json--"+jsonValue);
            Vins vins1 = gson.fromJson(jsonValue, Vins.class);
            System.out.println("ddd"+vins1);
            Vin vin = new Vin();
            vin.setVin("544554");

            vins1.addVins(vin);

            jsonValue = gson.toJson(vins1).toString();

            BufferedWriter writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Amaresh\\Test\\sample_json.json"));
                writer.write(jsonValue);
                System.out.println("Test"+jsonValue);

            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
              try {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Setter Getter classes :

```
public class Vin {
    @Expose
    private String vin;

    public String getVin() {
        return vin;
    }

public void setVin(String vin) {
    this.vin = vin;
}

}


public class Vins {
    @Expose
    List<Vin> vins = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Vin> getVins() {
        return vins;
    }

    public void addVins(Vin vin) {
        this.vins.add(vin);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: if i comment line //String jsonValue = gson.toJson(list_string).toString(); 
and pass this value String jsonValue=list_string; 
which i am reading from file  error i am getting below error 
{"vins":[{"vin":"544554"},{"vin":"54554"}]}
[{"vin":"544554"}, {"vin":"54554"}]
amar1{"vin":"544554"}
amar1{"vin":"544554"}{"vin":"54554"}
amar{"vin":"544554"}{"vin":"54554"}
json--{"vin":"544554"}{"vin":"54554"}
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 18 path $

Comment: i am not getting how the new text field value i will append to existing data than write. Please help.

Comment: what library are you using ? since JSONParser is actually defined as JsonParser  in GSON library https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main Logic:**

you can see 4 blocks in the code

1. Reading the json file and parsing to a java `Object`
2. Casting de java `Object` to a `JSonObject`, parsing to a `JsonArray` and iterating the array printing the `JsonElement`s
3. Creating a new `Vin Object` and converting it to a `JSON String` using `Gson.toJson` method (2nd part is not required only illustrative purposes)
4. Creating a `JsonWriter`, creating a `Vins Object` and loading it with the original `JsonArray` and then adding a new element (that correspondents to the new `Vin Object` created in step #3, finally writing the `Vins Object` to the [new] file.

**Input:**

```
{"vins":[{"vin":"544554"},{"vin":"54554"}]}
```

**Output:**

```
{"vins":[{"vin":"544554"},{"vin":"54554"},{"vin":"3689"}]}
```

**Code**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class JSONFIlewrite {
    public static String Vinno_Read;
    public static List<String> linststring;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Amaresh\\Test\\sample_json.json"));



            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            linststring = new ArrayList<String>();
            // loop array
            JsonArray msg = (JsonArray) jsonObject.get("vins");
            Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = msg.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Vinno_Read = iterator.next().toString();
                System.out.println("Vinno_Read---->" + Vinno_Read);
            }



            Vin newVin = new Vin();
            newVin.setVin("3689");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(newVin);
            System.out.println("json---->" + json);



            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Amaresh\\Test\\sample_json2.json", false);
            JsonWriter jw = new JsonWriter(file);
            iterator = msg.iterator();
            Vins vins = new Vins();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                vins.addVin(gson.fromJson(iterator.next().toString(), Vin.class));
            }
            vins.addVin(newVin);
            gson.toJson(vins, Vins.class, jw);
            file.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Notes:**

Since I don't know what library you are using, I have updated the class names to be compatible to GSON.

I have also changed the method: `public void addVins(Vin vin)` in `Vins Class` to `public void addVin(Vin vin)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its working. I have one question if user enters a text data which is already present say Vin : 3689 already exist than i don't want to write duplicate entries to file how to achieve it.

Comment: For that,  in the 4 step, you need to ask IF the array CONTAINS already the new Vin , IF it does then skipping  it ELSE  then go ahead and adding the new Vin. So, now is your turn for coding it :)

Comment: I meant the `ArrayList` inside the `Vins` object.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the existing content and append the new content to the end of JSON file:

Example1:

```
new FileWriter(file,true);
```

or you can try example02:

```
FileWriter file= new FileWriter(JSONLPATH,true)
```